# Can I query my remaining quota for the Google Play Developer API?

Tags: android, google-api, quota, google-play-developer-api

We'd like to monitor our remaining quota for the Google Play Developer API so we know when we're approaching the limit.

Can we query our quota programmatically?

Comment: No there is no api for checking quota usage.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no api for checking quota usage